# Mapping Query SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to map between to tables and update locations using is their anyway using SQL to do this in one query my structure is as follows. The table are as follows mapping table below [image]

Then the detail table is

[image]

Is their a way in sql I can update location in the detail table where it equals animal store id and then replace it with geministore id  My SQL is very basic so why not provided an example of what I tried as dont no. Is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: Just a note: when posting questions involving databases it is very helpful to include the actual schema of the tables involved (as well as some sample data to work with).

Comment: @jpw ok I was trying to find a nice site like paste bin that allowed me to show it graphically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should accomplish what you want, but as it will change data be sure to do a backup to ensure you can undo the changes if they're incorrect. Also, since you didn't specify the table names I assumed they're named`locations`and`detail`which is probably incorrect so you'll have to adjust the names.

```
UPDATE detail
SET location = locations.GeminiStoreID
FROM detail
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.AnimalStoreID = detail.location
```